# Computational complexity of a feasibility LP with $m$ inequalities, in $d$ dimension?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity, decision-problems

How would you quantify the computational complexity of feasibility LPs? 
Say, for example, an LP with $m$ inequalities:

$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{a_i} \cdot \mathbf{x} \leq b_i, \quad i \in [m] \\
\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: This seems to depend on the method used to solve the LP.

Comment: There must be a order of complexity for the best/common methods; right?

Comment: It seems complicated. The simplex method runs down to inspecting vertices. While one can construct simplexes with $2^m$ vertices, thus exponential complexity, in practice it seems to be competetive with other methods.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the model of computation? I vaguely recall reading that LP was in P if one used [real RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_RAM), but in NP if one used Turing machines.